# Use CSS to define print page

Tags: php, css, browser, printing

The last few days I've been experimenting with defining CSS stylesheet that is configuring the page to be printed out.

This is my final solution, which is working (at least what I can see in the html output):
home.php being called initially:

```
<?php

   $_SESSION['pageWidth'] = 20;
   $_SESSION['pageHeight'] = 15;
   $_SESSION['pageOrientation'] = "landscape";  

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
                
        <?php 
            echo "<style type='text/css' media='print'>
                .card {
                    clear: both;
                    page-break-before: always;
                }
                .no-print, .no-print *
                {
                    display: none !important;
                }
                @page : left{
                    margin: 0.5cm;
                }
                @page : right{
                    margin: 0.5cm;
                }
                @page : top{
                    margin: 1.5cm;
                }
                /* https://docs.w3cub.com/css/@page/size */
                @page {
                    size: " . $_SESSION['pageWidth'] + 2.5 ."cm " . $_SESSION['pageHeight'] + 2.5 . "cm " . $_SESSION['pageOrientation'] . " !important;
                }
            </style>";
        ?>
    </head>
```

During using integrated php files (called by `include "cardGenerator.php";`), the `session_variables` are updated with other values (width, height and maybe orientation, depending on the content).

Unfortunately, even my initial set values are ignored by browsers even though in the browser session, it looks all good: [image: header looking quite promising]

I've been trying it with chrome, edge and firefox - all of them ending up in ignoring the `@page{size: }` statement.

Does anybody have an idea or same experiences with browsers?

I've been doing this:

- put variable values into session to overwrite these value from any php file at any time and to integrate it into css
- put css `<style> </style>` section into header of home.php which is the "leading" php
- trying to print out from chrome, edge, firefox
- trying with different width/height values
- checked many solutions in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During studying some additional material, I've realized that defining a width and a height actually leads to kind of a landscape/portrait. So this information is obsolete. My working code:

```html
<?php 
            echo "<style type='text/css' media='print'>
                .card {
                    clear: both;
                    page-break-before: always;
                }
                .no-print, .no-print *
                {
                    display: none !important;
                }
                @page : left{
                    margin: 0.5cm;
                }
                @page : right{
                    margin: 0.5cm;
                }
                @page : top{
                    margin: 1.5cm;
                }
                /* https://docs.w3cub.com/css/@page/size */
                @page {
                    size: " . $_SESSION['pageWidth'] + 2.5 ."cm " . $_SESSION['pageHeight'] + 2.5 . "cm !important;
                }
            </style>";
        ?>
```

So, hopefully, this helps other with similar issues. As well as my approach on passing PHP variables into a stylesheet.